# Using Git for Windows' 'git' out of '--exec-path' (MSYS2) from Cygwin

Tags: cygwin, msys2, git-for-windows

Git for Windows uses MSYS2 which is derived from Cygwin. While the location where "cygdrive" (Cygwin uses `/cygdrive`, MSYS2 uses `/`) gets mounted, differs by default, it can be brought into a form that *is* be compatible between both flavors which is prefixed `/proc/cygdrive` (using `cygpath -U ...`).

#### Why do I need this?

1. while Cygwin features a `git` package, there is no `git-lfs`. This led to quite some confusion initially, because the `Git/cmd/git-lfs` from Git for Windows was found and used by Cygwin, but turned out to be incompatible with the `git` from Cygwin's package. Sure, I could build my own `git-lfs`, but I don't want to. I want to leverage the Git for Windows installation that is already installed on our developers' systems.
2. Process creation on Windows in the Win32 subsystem is much more expensive than a `clone()` or `fork()` on -- say -- Linux. Therefore I would like to avoid the complexity in my script to call `cygpath` across all sorts of of `git` invocations in one environment, but not the other ... so avoiding the spawning of additional processes is a real performance factor.

#### The problem

From the perspective of MSYS2 there is no Cygwin environment, so it gets to see the path for external tools, i.e. `%ProgramFiles%\Git\cmd`, hence `C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.exe` (or from Cygwin's perspective: `/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Git/cmd/git`).

This "flavor" of `git` expects the path in Windows respresentation, i.e. the form that `cygwin -w` or `cygwin -m` spit out.

Using `"/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Git/cmd/git" --exec-path` I am able to find the **canonical** path for Git for Windows' "exec directory":

```
$ cygpath -Ua "$("$(type -p git)" --exec-path)"
/proc/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core
```

Inquiring `--exec-path` again I can determine if this is the end of the indirection.

So, by using the following, I can populate a shell variable `GITBIN` with the *absolute canonical path* to `git` from Git for Windows, which ought to work in Cygwin and MSYS2 alike:

```
GITBIN="$(cygpath -Ua "$("$(type -p git)" --exec-path)")/git"
```

At this point I would expect that I can call `$GITBIN` using an *absolute canonical path* retrieved on the MSYS2 side using `cygpath -Ua ...`.

Suppose the `git` repo I want to act on is checked out in `/proc/cygdrive/x/gitrepo` and Cygwin lets me change into that directory or list its contents.

#### Question

Why does the following fail?:

```
$ "$GITBIN" -C "/proc/cygdrive/x/gitrepo" status
fatal: cannot change to '/proc/cygdrive/x/gitrepo': No such file or directory
```

---

#### What I also tried

[MSYS2 allows to use environment variables to control implicit path conversion](https://www.msys2.org/docs/filesystem-paths/). I have tried starting `$GITBIN` as follows:

```
env MSYS_NO_PATHCONV=1 "$GITBIN" -C /proc/cygdrive/x/gitrepo status
```

I also tried setting `MSYS2_ARG_CONV_EXCL="-C"` and I tried using `--work-tree=/proc/cygdrive/x/gitrepo/.git` instead of `-C /proc/cygdrive/x/gitrepo` in all permutations with these environment variables. But no luck ... the only difference was that the error message reads now `fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git`.

Then I even tried to coerce the `$GITBIN` into thinking it runs inside MSYS2 by setting environment variables, but admittedly I could be missing some:

```
env MINGW_CHOST=x86_64-w64-mingw32 MINGW_PREFIX=/mingw64 MSYSTEM_CARCH=x86_64 MSYSTEM_CHOST=x86_64-w64-mingw32 MSYSTEM_PREFIX=/mingw64 MSYSTEM=MINGW64 "$GITBIN" -C /proc/cygdrive/x/gitrepo status
```

Nothing seems to convince MSYS2 *from the outside* to consider the passed path already to be suitable for it and only internally convert it.

Answer (score 1):

So far the only *workaround* I have found is to use the representation that `cygpath -m` returns across MSYS2 *and* Cygwin. I.e. basically Windows paths with a drive letter, but forward slashes instead of backslashes, e.g. `X:/gitrepo` for `/proc/cygdrive/x/gitrepo` from the question.

This seems to be more "portable" even than the representation that `cygpath -Ua` returns.

But this was all deduced from observation of the behavior and not from looking at the code.

**NB:** If there is someone who can **1)** at least explain why the MSYS2-`git.exe` refuses the provided path and **2a)** provide a working alternative with `cygpath -Ua` **or 2b)** provide authoritative sources that confirm that `cygpath -m` *should* be used across the board, I shall accept and upvote *that* answer.